# Haskell ghci cannot load file

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am new to Haskell and trying to play around with it. Therefore I want to define some functions in a file and then load them in `ghci`.

I have a file called `tryout.hl` which I want to load in `ghci` using either
`:l tryout` or `:load tryout.hl`. With both commands I get `target ‘tryout’ is not a module name or a source file`.

What am I doing wrong?

Here  is my shell history:

```
[user@pc](~/proggin/haskell)$ ls -lah
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 user users 4.0K Oct 14 05:07 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 user users 4.0K Oct 13 07:51 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user users  138 Oct 14 05:07 tryout.hl

[user@pc](~/proggin/haskell)$ cat tryout.hl 
take' :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]  
take' n _  
    | n <= 0   = []  
take' _ []     = []  
take' n (x:xs) = x : take' (n-1) xs 

[user@pc](~/proggin/haskell)$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :!pwd
/home/user/proggin/haskell
Prelude> :!ls
tryout.hl
Prelude> :l tryout
target ‘tryout’ is not a module name or a source file
Prelude> :load tryout.hl
target ‘tryout.hl’ is not a module name or a source file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haskell source files should end with an extension of `hs`. Renaming your file should make it work:

```
$ mv tryout.hl tryout.hs
```

Demo in `ghci`:

```
λ> :l tryout.hl
target ‘tryout.hl’ is not a module name or a source file
λ> :l tryout.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tryout.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
```